# how do I add a favicon to RSS feed in Bitnami Drupal?

Tags: feeds

I have the Bitnami Drupal AMI that is on the [AWS marketplace](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/ref=bill_eml_1?sku=5ysj40wf1vkv5qwu3jszwhefa). I have set up a blog and it is being syndicated at another site.

Everything is working great (the Bitnami Drupal AMI rocks), but (you knew there was a "but") I see other blogs that are being syndicated and they have favicons.

How can I get a favicon into my Drupal blog's RSS feed so a favicon shows up when that feed is syndicated at another site?

Comment: Have you set a favicon for the Drupal site itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify the line 1611 of the file *installdir/apps/drupal/htdocs/includes/theme.inc*. Change feed.png for the name of your image previously placed in the folder *installdir/apps/drupal/htdocs/misc/*

The original line is:

```
  if ($image = theme('image', 'misc/feed.png', t('Syndicate content'), $title)) {
```